# Why GridView show only limited item?

Tags: android, gridview

I implemented the GridView like doc says [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html). According to example 22 item / image should appear, with vertical scrolling, but for me only 9 image appears. Why?

Guess something wrong in the setup of the `GridView`?

```
<GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:columnWidth="100dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="9"
        android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="true"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        android:stretchMode="none"
        android:verticalSpacing="1dp">
```

getCount method returns 22, and I have 22 image in my list.

```
public int getCount() {

    int jj = mThumbIds.length;
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.printable_number_5, R.drawable.printable_number_5,
        R.drawable.printable_number_5, R.drawable.printable_number_5,
        R.drawable.printable_number_5, R.drawable.printable_number_5,
        R.drawable.printable_number_5, R.drawable.printable_number_5,
        R.drawable.printable_number_5, R.drawable.printable_number_5,
        R.drawable.printable_number_5, R.drawable.printable_number_5,
        R.drawable.printable_number_5, R.drawable.printable_number_5,
        R.drawable.printable_number_5, R.drawable.printable_number_5,
        R.drawable.printable_number_5, R.drawable.printable_number_5,
        R.drawable.printable_number_5, R.drawable.printable_number_5,
        R.drawable.printable_number_5, R.drawable.printable_number_5
};
```

Comment: check it you have 22 items in your list?

Comment: Should present the same image 22 times, and `getCount` returns 22.

Comment: okay, can you add your adapter code. also, add a log in the `onBindViewHolder` method to check its called 22 times

Comment: `getView` is called for all the 22 position.

Comment: try setting `android:numColumns="auto_fit"`

Comment: thanks, that was the trick

Comment: your question does not make sense. you say you have 22 items and only see 9 but getView gets called 22 times...so how do you know you only have 9 items?

Comment: also, i thought you were using a recyclerview with a gridlayout. my bad. but   that isn't a bad option either. plus, recyclerview are much better